# Handling multiple request for a detection algorithm - Inception V2

Tags: python, deep-learning, multiprocessing

For a single image at a time, the detection algorithm works like a charm. But, when I pass multiple images at once, it just crashes.

I had it working on a CPU server earlier by wrapping it around multiprocessing and closing it every time a detection completed.
Here is the code for that:

```
def process_detection_pipeline(self, front, inputdata):
        try:
            manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
            return_dict = manager.dict()

            def worker_process(return_dic, front, inputdata):
                userid = inputdata['userid']
                if front is not None:
                    frontcrpimg, statusmin, statusmax = self.obj_detectperson.getUserCropImg(front)
                    cv2.imwrite('output/' + str(userid) + '/cropimgs/front.jpg', frontcrpimg)
                    return_dic['1'] = statusmin
                    return_dic['2'] = statusmax
                    return_dic['3'] = frontcrpimg

            p = Process(target=worker_process, args=(return_dict, front, inputdata))
            p.start()
            p.join()
            return return_dict.values()
        except:
            return False, False, None
```

The same code block is not working in the case of a GPU-based server.

I would like to know if there is a better solution to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The python multi-processing works with CPU and not GPU's,  the ML layer  like tensorflow will enable you to specify which device to use while running your program - however the parallelism in python - will always be based on underlying CPU available.

If you want to use GPU for python to multi-process - there is a lib available out there called - [PyCuda](https://documen.tician.de/pycuda/) go through it.

If this is not what you are asking for - please provide more information on your specifics of the issue

Comment: My main concern revolves around handling multiple requests for image detection at a time. 
I tried this solution on CPU because it was closing a particular request after being done with returning the cropped part of the detected image.

If other library or ways that can help in solving this problem would be highly appreciated. Thank you.